# Can the Loedel reference frame be used as the basis for establishing "Loedel age difference" as a viable term?

Tags: special-relativity, time, coordinate-systems, observers

When I first posted on the PSX, I kept using the term "age difference" as meaning something other than the term "reciprocal time dilation". It turns out that age difference here means the coordinate time difference between where a perspective's line of simultaneity intersects the two velocity lines. Basically, it means the same as reciprocal time dilation.

So at .6c if Bob's line of stationary simultaneity intersects his velocity at t=4 and Alice's at t'=3.2, the age difference is 4-3.2=.8.

But from the Loedel reference frame, which is defined on wiki as the frame of reference in which two collinear velocities become equal speeds in opposite directions, the Loedel velocity of 1/3c lends a perspective and Loedel lines of simultaneity where the Loedel age difference is 4-4=0 according to this Md:

[image: Loedel age difference]

The Loedel reference frame's lines of simultaneity join coordinate times that match the time labels of proper time. In conjunction with this question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/526395/), the Loedel age difference gives a picture of how age difference progresses for proper time coordinate labels (but not proper time itself as that is invariant of perspective [more info why here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/524386/)).

So my question is whether "Loedel age difference" can be used as a valid term distinct from the term "age difference" used here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102752/discussion-on-question-by-ralfcis-in-the-twin-paradox-one-twin-is-unambiguously).

Comment: Hi, we've noticed that you have made a large number of minor edits to this post. Please be mindful that every edit bumps the post in the "active" tab of the site and try to make your edits substantial. If you foresee improving this post repeatedly, maybe collect several edits and make them in one go instead of submitting them individually.

Comment: The terms "Loedel age difference", "Loedel reference frame" do not appear anywhere on the internet outside of this question or other posts by you on our site. It does not seem as if your edits make this question clearer or more understandable to others. You've edited this question 11 times after Chris asked you not to do so many edits, we are now at revision 38. At this point, it is impossible to tell whether this is in any meaningful sense an "edit" of the first version or an entirely different question. Please do not edit this post any further; ask a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: Why were all my comments deleted by a person unknown and no record of them having existed? @Chris

Comment: @ralfcis They were not deleted by me, but most likely it's because you continued to post comments here instead of using the chat room intended for that purpose and/or they were deleted as "no longer needed" as they were not suggestions to improve the post or responses to said suggestions.

Comment: They were 100% mathematical backing and clarification of the question and its importance. Would you prefer if I entered them as an answer to the question.

Comment: @ralfcis In general, comments are subject to be deleted at any time- you shouldn't assume they will hang around. This holds especially when a chat room has already been created expressly for that purpose.

Comment: Ok, another lesson learned but I am getting a bit paranoid with all the downvotes, closures, deletions and banishment with no explanation other than more "clarity" required. So I respond with math clarity and that is not received well as it takes effort to understand. Anyways, can I reformat them as an answer?

Comment: @Chris To the people who keep voting to keep this question closed. Terminology is important for clarity and brevity. Are you guys denying there are different perspectives due to velocity? Are you saying the half speed perspective is not valid or unimportant enough to warrant its own term "Loedel perspective"? Do you insist I call it "the perspective between 2 frames moving in opposite directions with equal speed"? (Wiki) Why not side with brevity?

Comment: This post has been through the reopen queue 11 times now, and been rejected every time. Please do not put it in there again in its current form.

Comment: Change the rules so that OP's can't vote to reopen their own posts. Over time there have been others who voted to reopen and if my math wasn't anonymously deleted maybe it would have been. I've been told to stop editing  so I did.

Answer (score 3):

You are playing fast and loose with notations like $t$, $t'$, and $t''$, assigning them different meanings at different stages in your analysis. So let's fix some meanings:

$t$ is  Bob's time coordinate.

$t'$ is  outbound-Alice's time coordinate.

$t''$ is inbound-Alice's time coordinate.

$E$ is the event where Alice starts her journey.  $F$ is the event where she reaches her destination and turns around.  $G$ is the event where she arrives back home.

Then:

$t(E)=t'(E)=0\quad t''(E)=-4.5$.

$t(F)=5\quad t'(F)=t''(F)=4$.

$t(G)=10\quad t'(G)=12.5\quad t''(G)= 8$.

It **makes no sense** to write things like $t=Yt'$.  You must first **specify an event** where you're measuring.   [You will in fact sometimes see equations like $t=Yt'$ in print, but only when it's already clear which event we're evaluating at.]

It **makes no sense** to ask whether an equation is true "from Alice's perspective".  An equation is either true or false, period.  $t'(F)=(4/5)t(F)$, from **any** "perspective".  And $t(G)=(4/5)t'(G)$, from **any** "perspective".

In fact, every single place where you use the undefined word "perspective", you are creating amibguity and setting yourself up for sloppy reasoning.  I strongly suggest that you review your writings and eliminate this and other undefined terms wherever they occur.

This should fully answer all of your conceptual questions. The answer to most of your vocabulary questions is "No, there are no standard names for these things, in some cases because you're asking about the names of things you've never clearly defined."

And the main lesson is:  It's not enough to just string a bunch of words and symbols together.  Words need meanings, and if you don't stick to those meanings, you are only going to confuse yourself and frustrate everyone who tries to help you.

Comment: 1. She travels 4 yrs each way. 2.  All perspectives including Alice's agree at co-location at t'=8 that Alice is 8 and Bob is 10 but at 6ly separation, Alice's perspective is she is she is t'=8 and Bob is t''=6.4. 3. What is your answer because I've seen many. 4. t=Yt' from Bob's perspective and t'=Yt'' from Alice's. 5. I'm just interested in the names of what I've described not in the million others. I assume you're saying there are no proper names for the proper time perspective.

Comment: @ralfcis:  If you insist on using notation like $t$ and $t'$ in some nonstandard way known only to you, then only you can understand or answer your questions.  If you insist on using phrases like "Alice's perspective" to mean two different things in the same sentence, then your questions will never make sense in the first place.  And if you choose to just keep ignoring these issues, people are very quickly going to give up on even **trying** to help you.

Comment: I realise my questions don't make sense because I don't know the terms.I want to learn the terms so I'm describing them. t=Yt' where t is from Bob's perspective blue line of simultaneity and t'=Yt'' from Alice's perspective red line of simultaneity. For Alice's time of t'=8, Bob's is t=10 and t''=6.4. What are your terms. All I have is Brian Greene's terms from his on-line course.

Comment: PS. and I realise Alice's lines of simultaneity point upwards on the inbound leg but at co-location the red line is a point, not a line. At the turnaround point I've heard so many interpretations of how that 2yrs disappears at the co-location point (correct term?) that any answer I give will be wrong to someone so I don't want to give my answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your notation but I've never seen that before.

Comment: @ralfcis Edits are meant to improve a post without deviating from the original author's intent. Adding a whole bunch of math and Minkowski diagrams to this post would not make the points in this answer any more clear.

Comment: I guess this isn't like the movies where professors can just read math directly off a sheet in front of them. But if they could, the points would be much clearer of why the Loedel perspective is important  (not just like any other perspective) and hence why it deserves its own term.

Comment: @Willo I've decoded what you tried to tell me into this Md. https://photos.app.goo.gl/JA8iwFX7yboAvYfdA. I've never seen this format and it's not used in popsci relativity. This is the format used https://photos.app.goo.gl/Cp7FjpQ3Rmhp9VYB6  t'=t/Y and t''=t'/Y=t/YY. The ' represents how many times gamma is used. t(E)=t′(E)=t′′(E)=0. t(F)=5, t′(F)=4, t′′(F)=3.2 from Alice's perspective outbound to t''(F)= 6.8 from Alice inbound. t(G)=10, t′(G)=8, t′′(G)=10. We don't use the same language so you'll never be able to read what I write. Brian Greene's course did not use your format at all.

Comment: @willo If your answer is the method professional relativists use, it sacrifices physical reality in order to get rid of the notion of equations changing due to perspective. The reality is Alice's journey is not 2 separate worldlines of inbound and outbound, it is 1 worldline of outbound to inbound. Alice's or Bob's perspectives do change the equations plus I even dispute the popsci version about Alice's perspective. It is not https://photos.app.goo.gl/Cp7FjpQ3Rmhp9VYB6 . It is https://photos.app.goo.gl/M1Ncn5LVD9padAds9 according to my math which no one has yet disputed (or even looked at).

Comment: @Chris I hope my last 2 comments clarify things for you. I have presented the math so there should be mostly mathematical counter-arguments of where my math contradicts relativity which it does not. This should be easy for any true expert to prove wrong and not through anonymous moderator deletions of my math to silence my argument. Correct math is correct math.

Comment: @Chris I hate to be a bother  but I've noticed that over the last 2 months many more new people have voted to reopen this question than the same minority that votes to keep it closed. I'm sure you have your policies but isn't one of them requiring at least 5 votes to keep it closed and yet it's always 3 from the same small group. Why does this group not wish to meet this topic head on with their overwhelming expertise? Instead they have been silently blocking this discussion from happening. I have shown in my discussions with Dale I am open to change so what's the real problem?

Comment: @ralfcis The system is working as designed- 3 leave closed votes removes it from the reopen queue. The physics SE mods have no ability to change this. In any case, your premise isn't true- your question has been through the reopen queue 5 times and received "Leave Closed" votes from 10 unique people.

Comment: Yikes, you are right. I had convinced myself it was the same 3 people and I had a majority which I don't. I apologise for that but more sorry that this discredits the rest of what I said.